# Retrieve data from SQL Server based on data column in datatable Epplus C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, epplus

My program able to read excel into datatable using epplus C# and there's a barcode column with data. I need to add & get bookcode data column from SQL Server based on data in barcode column. How will the SQL query be able to get each cell data row from the barcode column? I am confused to get the data by column or row.

I managed to get the SQL Server connection and 1 bookcode so far. I think I have to do looping to get all the bookcode for all the barcode column data but I'm not sure with the sequence in my coding and SQL connection. I believe I almost there to get it, hope you guys can assists me as this is my first project in C# :)

```
public void filldatagridview(ExcelWorksheet workSheet)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    // Create the data column
    for (int col = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Column; col <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Column; col++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(col.ToString());
    }

    // for (int row = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Row; row <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++)
    for (int row = 12; row <= 26; row++)
    {
        DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow(); //Create a row
        int i = 0;

        for (int col = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Column; col <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Column; col++)
        {
            newRow[i++] = workSheet.Cells[row, col].Text;
        }

        dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }

    dt.Columns.RemoveAt(0); //remove No 
    dt.Columns.RemoveAt(0); //remove article

    //Get BookCode
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=10.0.0.10;Database=;UserID=;Trusted_Connection=False");

    string query = "SELECT BookCode FROM Inventory WHERE Barcode='" + dt.Rows[1]["3"].ToString().Trim() + "'"; //3 is column for barcode            

    // looping logic here?
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
    } 

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    conn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);

    dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;

    conn.Close();
    da.Dispose();
}
```

UPDATED:

Able to get data from sql server based on barcode column in "3" as attached in the following image:

[image]

Currently facing problem with the order I receive from database in BOOKCODE column. Where supposedly it should follow like in this image:

[image]

Comment: This question is too complex, you have 2 different technologies and seemingly mashed them all in the one question. Maybe this should be 2 questions, how to read a column from Epplus into a list of string, and how to write a query to filter by a list of string

Comment: Currently I just wanted to know how the looping to get the barcode column as the sql query above managed to read that 1 cell as I only specified at dt.Rows[1]["Bookcode"].ToString().Trim() and print out BookCode column with data

Comment: @Nebula9 for your `BookCode` you can create a `comma(,)` separated string and then later in your `SQL` code you can call an `IN` query to get all the result in a single table instead of looping. Like:`var query = "SELECT BookCode FROM Inventory WHERE Barcode in("+bookCodes+")";`.

Comment: Oh so i dont need to looping, great but I couldnt get how and where should i create the comma separated string?

Comment: If the Barcode and BookCode are from different sources you may want to load and combine each one into a single list and use it to populate the excel worksheet so that you only have one loop. Make one sql query to load the data that you will need to populate the excel worksheet.

Comment: @Nebula9 just before you `SQL` code you can get all the `bar codes` from the already created `dt` like: `var barCodes = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("barCodes Column name from datatable goes here")).ToArray();` and later on create a `string` with comma separated bar codes as:`var barCodesstring = string.Format("'{0}'",string.Join("','",barCodes));` and then later use the string on `SQL` code with an `IN` Query.

Comment: @vikscool thank you its working! thank you very much for the simple solution

Comment: @vikscool I just realize the data I got doesnt match in order as in barcode column, why is this happening?

Comment: @Nebula9 can you please edit your question and post the **Order Required** and the **Order you Received**.

Comment: @vikscool updated the question

Comment: @Nebula9 as per your data it looks like you have to add an `order by` clause to your `SQL` query over `Barcode` column. As the `BookCode` order you need has some `null` values which are related to the `barCodes` given. And also make sure that the `barCode` given in the `IN()` clause have null values with them else it will not be selected.

Comment: The barcode column in datatable are not from sql, its from excel file. That means i need to do the condition smth like this right as well as the bookcode? `if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(row["barCodescolumn"]))
                {
                    //not null
                } else {//null }`

Comment: @Nebula9 arent you making a query to the `BookCode`'s stored in the `Inventory` table from your database that is related to the `BarCode` given?